# Android application unable to start activity

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, android-logcat

Hello I am programming an android application that has a database that allows the user to search through it for specific events.  Currently I am running into an issue with the activity getting started. I am testing this application on my Droid Bionic device and I am using eclipse SDK 4.2 to program.  How do I get my activity started? I am new to android and everything I've learned up to this point has been through me teaching myself and other tutorials online.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main Activity where the db is created:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity 
{
    EditText dEdit;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LocalDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Business";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "business text not null, address text not null, phone text not null,hours text not null,website text not null,type text not null" 
        + ")";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public MainActivity(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private  class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try{
            mDB=db;
            mDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {   
            try{
                mDB=db;
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Business");
            onCreate(mDB);
            }catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public MainActivity open() throws SQLException 
    {
        mDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String business, String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEB, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_BUSINESS,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_HOURS,
                KEY_WEB,
              KEY_TYPE}, 
                null, 
              null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                mDB.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_BUSINESS, 
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_PHONE,
                        KEY_HOURS,
                        KEY_WEB,
                        KEY_TYPE
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String business, 
    String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_HOURS,hours);
        args.put(KEY_WEB,website);
        args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return mDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }



}
```

Data added to the DB:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class DBActivity extends Activity {
    //MainActivity eventsData;
    //EditText output;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity db= new MainActivity(this);

        //output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        //type.setOnClickListener(
        //      new OnClickListener(){
        //          public void onClick(View view){
        //              Log.v("Entry",dEdit.getText().toString());
            //      }
        ///     });


        //try{String destPath="/data/data" +getPackageName()+ "/databases/BloomBusiness";
        //  File f = new File(destPath);
        //  if(!f.exists()){
        //      CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        //  }
        //  
        //  
        //}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}catch(IOException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}

        db.open();

        //inserting all data
        long id; 
        id =db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","419 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");


        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","316 W. 6th Street Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5300", "M-Sat:7AM-10PM Sun:9AM-9PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","3220 E. 3rd Street Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sun:8AM-10PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Uptown Cafe","102 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-0900", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM", "http://www.the-uptown.com/","Cajun-Creole");
        id=db.insertTitle("Crazy Horse","214 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-8877", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun:Noon-Midnight", "http://www.crazyhorseindiana.com/","Restaurant & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("FARMbloomington","108 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0002", "Tue.-Thurs.:8AM-10PM F:8AM-1AM Sat: 10AM-3AM Sun: 10AM-10PM","http://www.farm-bloomington.com","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("Laughing Planet","322 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2233", "M-Sun:11AM-9PM","http://www.facebook.com/laughingplanetbtown","Burritos & Salads");
        id=db.insertTitle("Soma Coffeehouse","322 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-331-2770", "M-Sat:7AM-11PM Sun:8AM-11PM","http://www.iheartsoma.com","Coffee House");
        id=db.insertTitle("Upland Brewing Company","350 W. 11th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2337", "M-Thurs:11AM-Midnight F-Sat:11AM-1AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.uplandbeer.com","Brewery & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("Nick's English Hut","423 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-332-4040", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.nicksenglishhut.com","Bar & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Village Deli","409 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2303", "M-F:7AM-8PM Sat-Sun 8AM-8PM","http://www.villagedeli.biz","Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner");
        id=db.insertTitle("Rachael's Cafe","300 E. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-330-1882", "M-F:8AM-9PM Sat-Sun 9AM-9PM","http://www.rachaelscafe.com","Coffee House & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("Happy Pig","1604 W. 7th St. Bloomington, IN", "None", "W:Sample Gates Noon-3PM Thurs:Sample Gates Noon-3PM F:Atlas Bar 11:30PM-3:30AM Sat:Courthouse Square 11:30PM-3:30AM","http://www.happypigbloomington.com","BBQ Streetfood");
        id=db.insertTitle("Lennie's Restaurant and Brewpub","1795 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2112", "Sun-Th:11AM-11PM F-Sat 11AM-Midnight","http://www.lenniesgourmetpizza.com","Bar & Restaurant");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1791 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7737", "Sun-Tues:11AM-2AM Wed-Thur: 11AM-3AM F-Sat:11AM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1610 W. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2522", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","877 S. College Mall Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-355-5000", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
}
```

Searching the DB:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class DBUse extends Activity  {
    EditText dEdit;
    SQLiteDatabase data;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity datab = new MainActivity(this);

        Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
        buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);



        Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);

        dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        datab.open();


        Cursor c = datab.getAllTitles();
        if((c!=null) && c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{DisplayTitle(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
        datab.open();
        Cursor b = datab.getAllTitles();

        if ((b!=null) && b.moveToFirst())
            DisplayTitle(b);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        data.close();

    data.close();


    }



//displays the data

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)  {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5)+
        "Type" + c.getShort(6),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    //Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v) {

            Cursor cur=data.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);
            String result="";

            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";
            };
            return;
        }

    };      
//Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick (View v){
            Cursor cur=data.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where type like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);
            String result="";
            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";


            };
            return;
        };


    };

}
```

The Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.database"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.database.DBUse"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Finally the LogCat:

```
04-28 17:27:15.055: E/Trace(721): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 17:27:16.124: D/dalvikvm(721): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 2% free 10842K/11011K, paused 44ms, total 48ms
04-28 17:27:16.134: I/dalvikvm-heap(721): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.204MB for 614416-byte allocation
04-28 17:27:16.274: D/dalvikvm(721): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 76ms+16ms, total 141ms
04-28 17:27:16.324: D/dalvikvm(721): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
04-28 17:27:16.334: I/dalvikvm-heap(721): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.245MB for 1093136-byte allocation
04-28 17:27:16.474: D/dalvikvm(721): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12508K/12743K, paused 75ms+6ms, total 132ms
04-28 17:27:16.544: D/AndroidRuntime(721): Shutting down VM
04-28 17:27:16.544: W/dalvikvm(721): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.DBUse}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at com.example.database.DBUse.onCreate(DBUse.java:67)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-28 17:27:16.556: E/AndroidRuntime(721):  ... 11 more
04-28 17:27:18.624: I/Process(721): Sending signal. PID: 721 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` on line 67 of `DBUse.java`. Find that line, and fix whatever problem is on it.

Note that your `onCreate()`, in two lines, calls `close()` on a `data` data member that you have never initialized.

Comment: Seems to me you nailed it. On reading the documentation for Cursor it seems that those calls don't return null on empty queries, like I thought they would.

Comment: Should I just get rid of the closes in that on create method all together? since I'm eventually closing the database anyway? Okay that's exactly what I did and things are working thanks so much!

Comment: @CommonsWare could you help me with another nullpointerexception that I'm getting?